# Символ начала комментария от иного диалекта или языка в ответе

Tags: поддержка, подсветка-синтаксиса

Возможно ли какое-то дополнительное форматирование кода в ответе(*4 сивола пробела вначале*), где есть символ или последовательность символов обозначения комментария не принадлежащему к диалекту кода или запроса, для корректного отображения содержимого ответа?

---

К примеру, в ответе по linux встречается последовательность символов типа `/*` и после нее весь текст выглядит как комментарий, данную последовательность обычно используют в SQL для отметки начала комментария.

[пример ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027242/341547)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Подсветка синтаксиса описана в вопросе на английской мете: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Stack Overflow для подсветки использует [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Для указания языка программирования вручную нужно перед блоком кода добавить комментарий:

```
<!-- language: код-языка -->

    здесь код
```

или, если блок кода выделен через ```:

````
```код-языка

здесь код
````

В случае bash нужно выбрать код языка `lang-bash`.

Обычно, язык для подсветки определяется автоматически по меткам в вопросе. Но в данном случае в вопросе есть метки [bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) и [shell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell). Каждой из этих меток соответствует свой код языка (`lang-bash` и `lang-sh` соответственно). В таких случаях Stack Overflow не проставляет код языка, в результате prettify пытается распознать язык по коду, что получается не очень.